# How to return data in separated function form the scrapy parse function?

Tags: python, return, scrapy, yield

I have a parse function using scrapy to get some data from a website, this function pass some data to another function withen this function, i can not return the output!, i tried it with print it worked but i need to use return to get the data in a json file.
How to make printed func return items?

```
def parse(self, response):
     all_tr= list()
     for tr in response.xpath('//tr').extract():
           all_tr.append(tr)
     tr_data = list()
     city_tr = list()
     for tr in all_tr:
           if re.findall(r'class="city".+name.+?<', tr):
             city_tr.append(tr)
           else:
             pass
     c= 0
     const =1
     while const ==1:
          try:
            start=city_tr[c]
            end= city_tr[c+1]
            indexStart=all_tr.index(start)
            indexEnd=all_tr.index(end)
            tr_data.append(all_tr[indexStart:indexEnd])
            c=c+1
          except IndexError:
            const=2
            tr_data.append(all_tr[all_tr.index(start):])
     for tr in tr_data:
          func_2(tr)
```

i have some operations in func_2, then passing it to another fnction "prin func"

```
def print_func(city,days, tr):
    if len(days)==0:
        item=PropertiesItem()
        item['Name']= ""
        item['City']= city
        item['State']= "CA"
        return item
```

print_func do not return anything, could anyone please tell my why?

Comment: Format your code properly so it is readable

Comment: @TarunLalwani done.
Do you have any idea about why print func do not return the item?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy checks the return value of the parse function. Now if you call a function inside it and discard it return value then you don't return anything from the parse function as such

So your code should change from

```
for tr in tr_data:
    func_2(tr)
```

to

```
for tr in tr_data:
    yield func_2(tr)
```

This will make sure whatever item `func_2` returns is passed to the scrapy framework. Also in your func_2 function you would be calling `print_func`, so you need to capture it return value and pass it back to the calling function

```
def func_2(....):
    ....
    item = print_func(...)
    ...
    return item
```

You need to get the value in parse function and then yield it from there. Just returning it from any function doesn't work.

Comment: I have so many nedsted functions. Can i pass the data back to the parse function then collecting them in a list for example, and looping the list for return?

Comment: Yes, you will need to yield in your main parse function, rest all place it would be return only. If you return a list then you can either use `yield from`. if you use python 2.x then just loop and yield the items

Answer (score 0):

For any other function inside **parse** method write this way :

```
def parse(self, response):
    for req in self.call_your_function(self, param):
        yield req
```

## or, in Python 3:

```
def parse(self, response):    
    yield from self.call_your_function(self, param)
```